# Why doesn't this closure have the arguments I expect?

Tags: swift, closures

I have a `SettingsViewController` and have created a struct to define the information required for each setting.

```
///Represents a list of the options needed to populate a `SettingsTableViewCell`
public struct Setting {
    ///The image to use for the icon
    var imageName : String

    ///The text to display as the title of the setting
    var title : String

    ///Called when the switch is tapped. If no closure is supplied, the switch is hidden
    var switchCallback: ((_ status: Bool)->())?
}
```

The view controller keeps an array of these settings to later be used in a table view. An example of one is provided below:

```
let options : [Setting] =
[
    Setting(imageName: "notifications", title: "Bump Notifications") {updateNotificationSetting($0)},
    ...
]
```

However, when I try to compile, I'm presented with the error:

```
Cannot convert value of type '(SettingsViewController) -> (Bool) -> ()' to expected argument type '((Bool) -> ())?'
```

Can somebody explain where the `(SettingsViewController)` is coming from, please? And if you can, what I need to change to fix it, please?

---

For an SSCCE, see below:

```
import UIKit

///Represents a list of the options needed to populate a `SettingsTableViewCell`
public struct Setting {
    ///The image to use for the icon
    var imageName : String

    ///The text to display as the title of the setting
    var title : String

    ///Called when the switch is tapped. If no closure is supplied, the switch is hidden
    var switchCallback: ((_ status: Bool)->())?
}



@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    let options : [Setting] =
    [
        //Error is on the following line
        Setting(imageName: "notifications", title: "Bump Notifications") {isOn in updateSetting(isOn)},
    ]

    func updateSetting(isOn : Bool) {

    }

}
```

Comment: from a `self` somewhere in your closure initialization.

Comment: There is no explicit `self` in the closure (see above), but I expect there is an implicit one in front of `updateNotifications($0)`. Any suggestions on how to call that function in this case then, please?

Comment: Not related, but in Swift 3 all parameter labels in callback closures have been removed. The callback signature – as revealed in the error message –  is just `(Bool) -> ()`, `status` is not used at all.

Comment: @rob, this isn't in a class method. It's in an instance level array variable.

Comment: @vadian, where do you see "status" please? I don't understand your comment?

Comment: In the `switchCallback` declaration line: `var switchCallback: ((Bool)->())?` is sufficient.

Comment: @vadian, ah ok thanks.

Comment: Can you create an MWE that does not refer to classes not visible here? At which line does the error occur?

Comment: @Raphael, I just stuck the code in the question into AppDelegate (see edit), nothing more is needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closure in your `Setting` initializer is capturing `self`. However, `self` in Swift is available only after all the properties of an object are initialized, that is, after `let options` is initialized.

One method to break the circle is to use lazy initialization of properties:

```
public struct Setting {
    var imageName : String
    var title : String
    var switchCallback: ((_ status: Bool)->())?
}

class MyClass {
    lazy var options: [Setting] = [
        Setting(imageName: "x", title: "X") { [unowned self] in self.updateSetting(isOn: $0)}
    ]

    func updateSetting(isOn : Bool) {}
}
```

Note the explicit type `: [Setting]` is currently required for the declaration.

Note you need to use `[unowned self]` or `[weak self]` to break the release cycle (thanks @rob for the comment).

Comment: @Rob In my testing there was no reference cycle, the object got deallocated but I would probably put `[unowned self]` just to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

> But (a) you have to have an explicit reference to `self` in the closure (e.g. `self.updateNotificationSetting`); and (b) to do that, you can only do that if you make it `lazy var` rather than `let` (allowing it to now resolve `self`).

Although I wasn't able to get this working with the keyword `lazy var`, this did give me the information I needed to solve the problem. I ended up essentially making my own lazy var, only instantiating it just before I use the array:

```
private var options : [Setting]!


...

if options == nil {
        options =  [
            Setting(imageName: "notifications", title: "Bump Notifications") {isOn in self.updateNotificationSetting(isOn: isOn)},
            Setting(imageName: "automatic_check_in", title: "Automatic Check In") {isOn in self.updateAutomaticCheckInSetting(isOn:isOn)},
            Setting(imageName: "logout", title: "Logout", switchCallback:nil)
        ]
    }
```

Comment: I'd suggest `weak` or `unowned` reference to `self`, e.g. `Setting(imageName: "automatic_check_in", title: "Automatic Check In") { [weak self] isOn in self?.updateAutomaticCheckInSetting(isOn: isOn) }`.